# SoapFault: looks like we got no XML document Magento and laravel

Tags: php, laravel, apache, ubuntu, magento

i am with a problem in my application Laravel, when i use the SoapClient, for example `my_object_soap->login();` returned this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] looks like we got no XML

I already tried several solutions that I researched in google and here, but I did not solve my problem.

my code follows:

```
    ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled",0);
    ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache",0);
    ini_set("error_reporting",-1);
    ini_set("display_errors","On");

    $wsdl_url = "https://example.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/?wsdl";
    $apiAuth = new \stdClass();
    $apiAuth->username = trim("myusermagento");
    $apiAuth->apiKey = trim("mykeymagento");

    try{
        $proxy = new SoapClient($wsdl_url,array('cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE, 'trace' => true));
        $session = $proxy->login($apiAuth);
        $data = $session;
        $status = true;
        $responseStatus = 200;
    } catch(SoapFault $e) {
        $error = $e->getMessage();
        $data = $proxy->__getLastResponse();
        $status = false;
        $responseStatus = 500;
    }        

    return Response::json([
        'success' => $status, 
        'data' => $data,
        'erros'=> $error,
    ],$responseStatus);
```

I have no idea which a problem, when i tested in SoapUI, with this user and key, it's alright, but in my app not.

My magento version app is 1.6.2, and my php is 7.2, I already tried to downgrade to php 5.6 because it could be incompatibility with the magento version and my php but it still did not work.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, structure your request as follows

```
    $options = array('trace'=> true,'exceptions' => true);            
    $client  = new \SoapClient('https://www.example.com?wsdl',$options);

    $params = new \stdClass();
    $params->key1 = 'XXXXXX';
    $params->Key2 = 'XXXXX';
    $soapVar = new \SoapVar($params,SOAP_ENC_OBJECT);

    $header = new \SoapHeader('https://www.example?wsdl','credentials',$soapVar);

    $client->__setSoapHeaders(array($header));


    $result=$client->login(function parameters here);
```

Cheers!!!

Comment: thanks, but this did not work, the same error persists!

Comment: Don't forget to try/ catch your request error above occur if client get some invalid xml  either the WSDL itself or the response returned.